# JAGS bayesian MCMC but came into this:Error parsing model file: syntax error on line 34 near "-"

Tags: if-statement, logical-operators, jags

`I would like to implement under jags a pseudo-code whose steps are provided in this paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1470160X12003676#upi0010
At step 9-10 which was to loop through steps 6-8 until a stopping rule was satisfied or all metrics were used, I keep getting the following error:Error in jags.model(textConnection(model_string), data = data_list, n.chains = 3) :

Error parsing model file:
syntax error on line 34 near "-"

Below is my code: `

```
model_string <- "
model {
  for (j in 1:J) {
    # Step 1: Reflect positively correlated metrics about midpoint
    mref[j, 1:I] <- max(metrics[j, ]) - metrics[j, 1:I]
    
    # Step 2: Initialize initial metric m1
    m[j, 1] <- mref[j, 1]
    
    # Step 3: Add m1 to each of the rest of the metrics, mj, site-by-site
    for (i in 2:I) {
      m[j, i] <- m[j, i - 1] + mref[j, i]
    }
    
    # Step 4: Find combination of m1 + mj with strongest negative correlation with D
    rho[j] <- cor(D[j], m[j, I])
    neg_rho[j] <- -1 * rho[j]
    
    # Step 5: Record correlation with D
    correlation_record[j, 1] <- rho[j]
    
    # Step 6: Add index to each of the remaining metrics mj site-by-site
    index[j, 1] <- m[j, I]  # Initialize index with m1
    
    # Step 7: Find combination of index + mj with strongest negative correlation with D
    rho_index[j] <- cor(D[j], index[j, 1])
    neg_rho_index[j] <- -1 * rho_index[j]
    
    # Step 8: Record correlation with D
    correlation_record[j, 2] <- rho_index[j]
    
    # Steps 9-10: Continue until stopping rule is satisfied or all metrics used
    for (i in 2:I) {
     ifelse (neg_rho_index[j]-(neg_rho[j] + correlation_threshold)< 0, index[j, i] <- 0, 
        {
        index[j, i] <- index[j, i - 1] + m[j, I - i + 1]
        rho_index[j] <- cor(D[j], index[j, i])
        neg_rho_index[j] <- -1 * rho_index[j]
        correlation_record[j, i + 1] <- rho_index[j]
        # Stop if improvement is below threshold
        stop[j] <- TRUE
        break
        })
    }
       
    # Step 11: Update I_used for each observation
    I_used[j] <- sum(index[j, ] > 0)
  }
}
"

# Generate simulated data
# Data
datas<-cbind(data[,1],data[,19:25])
metrics<-datas[,-1]
D<-datas$`data[, 1]`
N <- 276 # number of observations
J <- 276
I <- 7 # number of metrics
#correlation_threshold<-0.3  # Threshold for improvement
# Define list of data
data_list <- list("J"=J, "I"=I, "metrics"=metrics, "D"=D, "correlation_threshold"=0.1)

# Run JAGS model
model <- jags.model(textConnection(model_string), data = data_list, n.chains = 3)
```

Comment: I'm not certain, but I don't think you can do this in JAGS.  I don't think `break` is a defined function in JAGS and `ifelse()` doesn't work the way that I think you intend it there.  I think you might need to do all iterations from `2:I` for that loop, defining everything in each iteration then you can set the ones to zero that are below (or above) the intended threshold.